# Git not committing staged changes

Tags: git

After deleting / modifying files, I staged them by doing `git add -A`, and I also tried `git add -u` after. When I commit the changes I notice that git doesn't actually commit any of the changes. Git status still shows that the files are staged, and doing a git push tells me `everything is up to date`.

What can be the possible causes of this? Git status clearly shows the deletions and modifications.

Exact commands used:

`git add -A`

`git status` - shows all changes are staged as expected

`git commit -m 'message here'`

nothing gets committed so I tried `git add -u`

committed again with the same command, still nothing. Here is the output of git status after staging the files:

[image]

Comment: You need to commit. Git commit -m "your message"

Comment: @Christoph He said he did. But the staging area seems to have been empty at the time, thus no commit.

Comment: Try `git add --all`

Comment: @NoorAShuvo I've tried that as well

Comment: What `git log` says?

Comment: Please show the _exact_ commands used and their outputs?

Comment: "and their outputs" means the actual output of `git status`, if possible, not just "all changes are staged as expected".

Comment: @Useless I'm working on it. Had to work around it temporarily so I lost that specific session. When I get the chance I'll restore it and show that output

Comment: What happens if you reset the index (`git reset`) and then use `git add -p` to add changes per patch to the index? What output do you get?

Comment: @Josien same result as the screenshot I added

Comment: I have originally posted the answer but it was downvoted so I deleted it. Git behaves stupidly this way (even latest one as of today). `git add --all` does not do what it seems to do as OP observed. In order to be able to commit everything one also needs to call `git add .`. Don't know why but it works. So call both and your commit will actually commit all the staged changes recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the specific name of the files or directory? I always use  `git add .` or `git add ../something.txt` and I've never had an issue. I've only gotten funny business on git with changing branches.

If that still doesn't work, I'd try making a new local repo.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the expected behavior with the `-u` parameter :

> Update the index **just where it already has an entry** matching . This removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files.

(emphasis mine)

If you didn't *already* add these files, they won't be staged with `-u`. It's a way to tell git "I've modified these files *again* since last time adding them".

Why do you use the parameter in the first place? What did you try to achieve/avoid?

Comment: I'm trying to commit deleted and modified files, but git simply ignores them. They aren't present in `.gitignore` either. Doing a `git add -A` stages everything as expected but `git commit -m 'message here'` doesn't actually commit anything. To be honest, I used that parameter because it was recommended somewhere for this specific issue, and it actually worked once. But the issue has come back.

Answer (score 0):

> After deleting/modifying files, I staged them by doing git add -A, and I also tried git add -u

You only need to use `git add -A && git add -u` if you are using older git versions (>2.0). In Git >2.0 the default for git add id `git add -A`

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt

> When `git add -u` and `git add -A` are run inside a subdirectory
>   without specifying which paths to add on the command line, they
>   operate on the entire tree for consistency with `git commit -a` and
>   other commands (these commands used to operate only on the current
>   subdirectory).
>
> Say `git add -u .` or `git add -A .` if you want to limit the operation to the current directory.
>
> ---
>
> ## Since git version 2.0.0:
>
> **`git add <path>` is the same as `git add -A <path>` now**

So simply use this:

```
git add .
```

---

> When I commit the changes I notice that git doesn't actually commit any of the changes.

Looks like you did not committed any changes.

You also mentioned: ... *They aren't present in .gitignore either.* .
Run this command to view if the files are ignored or not

```
git check-ignore * -v
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The files aren't being ignored. I usually use `git add .` as well but git still isn't committing anything after running `git commit -m 'message'`. But when I check the status it clearly shows all the staged files in green.

Comment: Try `git commit --verbose`. What is the output?

Answer (score -1):

Use double quotation, I also had the same error.

```
git commit -m "your msg"
```